# I am using a Linux subsystem and I am unable to install Java or Jshell

Tags: java, windows-subsystem-for-linux, apt

Below is the error shown when I type 'sudo apt install openjdk-ll-jdk-headless':

```
harsha@DESKTOP-P5F1GV2:~$ sudo apt install openjdk-ll-jdk-headless
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package openjdk-ll-jdk-headless
```

Comment: Try `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` first. Your Linux system needs a catalogue refresh (the first command) and then a system update won't hurt either (the second command). Then you can do your install.

Comment: AFAIK `openjdk-ll-jdk-headless` doesn't exist. Try `openjdk-11-jdk-headless`.

Comment: I am using a linux subsystem in windows 10

Comment: E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution). is the error  after i ran the sudo apt install openjdk-11-jdk-headless

Comment: Please help me out

Comment: people are trying to help you out. they even suggested multiple possible solutions to your problem which, as far as i know, should work. 

please try them out, report the results and if it doesnt work describe which error you are still getting. 

asking for more help, when there already are recommendations for you to try out without any information whether it worked or not is not really giving others the vibe to help you more

Comment: @HarshavardhanKrishnachaitany In that case, do exactly what the error message says. Try `sudo apt --fix-broken install`. Usually reading and understanding the message helps a lot.